# How to multiply two tibbles with different dimensions in R?

Tags: r, tibble

When I multiply a vector by a matrix I do:

```
mat <- matrix(c(c(2,3),c(4,5)),2)
vec <- c(1,-1) 
vec * mat
```

I get

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    4
[2,]   -3   -5
```

But when I try to do something similar with tibbles, like

```
library(dplyr)
a <- tibble(x = c(1,-1))
b <- tibble(y = c(2,3), z = c(4,5))
c <- a*b
```

I get the error,

```
Error in Ops.data.frame(a, b) : 
  ‘*’ only defined for equally-sized data frames
```

In the same line of thought, how can I use `transmute` to multiply variable `x` by `y` and `x` by `z` in `tibble` d?

```
d <- tibble(x = c(1,-1), y=c(2,3), z= c(4,5))
```

Comment: in case of `tibble` multiplication, `t(a)` fixes your problem.

Comment: tibbles ≠ matrices. Matrix operations simply don’t make sense on them. If you want to perform matrix operations, why not use matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
d %>% mutate_at(vars(c(y, z)), ~.x*x)
```

or if you have more than two columns

```
d %>% mutate_at(vars(-x), ~.x*x)
```

Note that if you are working with an older version of the `dplyr` package you have to use a slightly different syntax which looks like this:

```
d %>% mutate_at(vars(-x), funs(. * x))
d %>% mutate_at(vars(c(y, z)), funs(. * x))
```